No funciona mi código VBA
comparto mi código, el error está al final
Private Sub Btn_Guardar_Click()
    Dim wsForm As Worksheet
    Dim wsDB As Worksheet
    Dim lastRowDB As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim validData As Boolean
    Dim errorMsg As String
    
    Set wsForm = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Form")
    Set wsDB = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DB")
    
    validData = True
    errorMsg = "Error: Las siguientes filas tienen datos incompletos:" & vbCrLf
    
    ' Verificar que la columna G esté correctamente completada
    For i = 12 To 46
        If wsForm.Cells(i, 6).Value = False And wsForm.Cells(i, 7).Value = "" Then
            validData = False
            errorMsg = errorMsg & "Fila " & i & ": Columna G debe tener un número si F es FALSO" & vbCrLf
        End If
    Next i

    
    If Not validData Then
        MsgBox errorMsg, vbExclamation, "Datos Incompletos"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Encontrar la última fila vacía en la hoja "DB"
    lastRowDB = wsDB.Cells(wsDB.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    
    ' Copiar valores de la Tabla_Formulario en la hoja "Form" a la hoja "DB"
    For i = 12 To 46
        If wsForm.Cells(i, 3).Value <> "" Or wsForm.Cells(i, 4).Value <> "" Or wsForm.Cells(i, 5).Value <> "" Then
            wsDB.Cells(lastRowDB, 1).Value = wsForm.Range("E4").Value ' Columna A
            wsDB.Cells(lastRowDB, 2).Value = wsForm.Range("E5").Value ' Columna B
            wsDB.Cells(lastRowDB, 3).Value = wsForm.Range("E6").Value ' Columna C
            wsDB.Cells(lastRowDB, 4).Value = wsForm.Cells(i, 3).Value ' Columna D
            wsDB.Cells(lastRowDB, 5).Value = wsForm.Cells(i, 7).Value ' Columna E
            wsDB.Cells(lastRowDB, 7).Value = wsForm.Cells(i, 5).Value ' Columna F
            
            lastRowDB = lastRowDB + 1
        End If
    Next i
    
    ' Limpiar los datos en la hoja "Form"
    wsForm.Range("F12:F46").Value = False ' Establece FALSE en el rango F12:F46
    
    ' Limpiar otras celdas y actualizar la fecha
    wsForm.Range("E5:E6").ClearContents
    wsForm.Range("E4").Value = Date
    
    ' Borrar los valores existentes en el rango G12:G46 antes de aplicar la fórmula
    wsForm.Range("G12:G46").ClearContents
    
    
    ' Mostrar mensaje de éxito
    MsgBox "Datos copiados con éxito", vbInformation, "Proceso Completado"
    
    ' Establecer la fórmula en el rango G12:G46
    For i = 12 To 46
        wsForm.Cells(i, 7).Value = "=SI(F" & i & "=VERDADERO; C" & i & "; """")"
    Next i

    ' Mostrar mensaje de éxito
    MsgBox "FIN", vbInformation, "Proceso Completado"
End Sub 

Todo el código funciona excepto la última parte,
     ' Establecer la fórmula en el rango G12:G46
    For i = 12 To 46
        wsForm.Cells(i, 7).Value = "=SI(F" & i & "=VERDADERO; C" & i & "; """")"
    Next i

y tampoco se muestra el mensaje de FIN, Pero no me muestra ningún mensaje de error o depuración. simplemente finaliza la ejecución, todo lo demás lo hace.

Utilicé esto para solucionarlo
    wsForm.Cells(12, 7).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF([@Cumlimiento]=TRUE,[@Cantidad],"""")"


La sintaxis de los msgbox es errónea, puede que tu fallo este en eso...


Private Sub Btn_Guardar_Click()
    Dim wsForm As Worksheet
    Dim wsDB As Worksheet
    Dim lastRowDB As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim validData As Boolean
    Dim errorMsg As String
    
    Set wsForm = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Form")
    Set wsDB = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DB")
    
    validData = True
    errorMsg = "Error: Las siguientes filas tienen datos incompletos:" & vbCrLf
    
    ' Verificar que la columna G esté correctamente completada
    For i = 12 To 46
        If wsForm.Cells(i, 6).Value = False And wsForm.Cells(i, 7).Value = "" Then
            validData = False
            errorMsg = errorMsg & "Fila " & i & ": Columna G debe tener un número si F es FALSO" & vbCrLf
        End If
    Next i

    
    If Not validData Then
        MsgBox( errorMsg, vbExclamation, "Datos Incompletos")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Encontrar la última fila vacía en la hoja "DB"
    lastRowDB = wsDB.Cells(wsDB.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    
    ' Copiar valores de la Tabla_Formulario en la hoja "Form" a la hoja "DB"
    For i = 12 To 46
        If wsForm.Cells(i, 3).Value <> "" Or wsForm.Cells(i, 4).Value <> "" Or wsForm.Cells(i, 5).Value <> "" Then
            wsDB.Cells(lastRowDB, 1).Value = wsForm.Range("E4").Value ' Columna A
            wsDB.Cells(lastRowDB, 2).Value = wsForm.Range("E5").Value ' Columna B
            wsDB.Cells(lastRowDB, 3).Value = wsForm.Range("E6").Value ' Columna C
            wsDB.Cells(lastRowDB, 4).Value = wsForm.Cells(i, 3).Value ' Columna D
            wsDB.Cells(lastRowDB, 5).Value = wsForm.Cells(i, 7).Value ' Columna E
            wsDB.Cells(lastRowDB, 7).Value = wsForm.Cells(i, 5).Value ' Columna F
            
            lastRowDB = lastRowDB + 1
        End If
    Next i
    
    ' Limpiar los datos en la hoja "Form"
    wsForm.Range("F12:F46").Value = False ' Establece FALSE en el rango F12:F46
    
    ' Limpiar otras celdas y actualizar la fecha
    wsForm.Range("E5:E6").ClearContents
    wsForm.Range("E4").Value = Date
    
    ' Borrar los valores existentes en el rango G12:G46 antes de aplicar la fórmula
    wsForm.Range("G12:G46").ClearContents
    
    
    ' Mostrar mensaje de éxito
    MsgBox( "Datos copiados con éxito", vbInformation, "Proceso Completado")
    
    ' Establecer la fórmula en el rango G12:G46
    For i = 12 To 46
        wsForm.Cells(i, 7).Value = "=SI(F" & i & "=VERDADERO; C" & i & "; " & ")"
    Next i

    ' Mostrar mensaje de éxito
    MsgBox( "FIN", vbInformation, "Proceso Completado")
End Sub 



